# Redirecting error messages

Tags: php

How do I redirect the error messages from my html_form_send.php back to my email.php page. Here is what I got, I have my form email.php:

**email.php**

```
<form name = 'htmlform' action = '$template/html_form_send.php' 
      method = 'post' class = 'form-horizontal well' >
```

My email.php links to my html_form_send.php which has the following code:

**html_form_send.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "my email";
    $email_subject = "my subject";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found \
            with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error . "<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) || !isset($_POST['password'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem \
            with the form you submitted.');       

        // and instead redirect the user to your error page
        header("Location: http://hurstblog.co.uk/contact-error");
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $password = $_POST['password']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if (!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not \
            appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not \
            appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (strlen($telephone) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The telephone you entered do not \
            appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (strlen($password) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The password you entered do not \
            appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: " . clean_string($name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: " . clean_string($email_from) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: " . clean_string($telephone) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Password: " . clean_string($password) . "\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n".
    'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

    if (mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {
        header("Location: http://domain.net");
    }
}
die();

?>
```

My question is how can I redirect the error?

Comment: what do you mean by redirect the error

Comment: Instead of using die(), redirect the page to email.php with the error passed on a GET variable.

Comment: :)  Send it back to my email.php page so that it will display on that page not on my html_form_send.php

Comment: How Jim Verastigue ?  Do you think you can post the code ?

Comment: If you can elaborate on the question, it's always better to do so yourself - feel free to edit it after you've asked if something comes to mind later.

Answer (score 0):

html_form_send.php

```
// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name'])){
    header("location: email.php?error=name");
}
if(!isset($_POST['email'])){
    header("location: email.php?error=email");
}
if(!isset($_POST['telephone'])){
    header("location: email.php?error=telephone");
}
if(!isset($_POST['password'])){
    header("location: email.php?error=password");
}

$name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$password = $_POST['password']; // required

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    header("location: email.php?error=invalid_email");
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    header("location: email.php?error=invalid_firstname");
}
if(strlen($telephone) < 2) {
    header("location: email.php?error=invalid_telephone");
}
if(strlen($password) < 2) {
    header("location: email.php?error=invalid_password");
}
```

The $_GET['error'] will contain the error ID, so in your email.php, you should put the error messages.

```
$error_message = "";
if($_GET['error']=='invalid_email'){
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if($_GET['error']=='invalid_firstname'){
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
```

//etc

```
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    echo($error_message);
}
```

Comment: I updated the code, the condition in the email.php was wrong, my bad. It should be if($_GET['error']=='invalid_firstname') then you should put the other error messages.

Comment: Are you sure that this code is valid?     if(strlen($password) < 2) {
    header("location: ../../../register.php?error=invalid_password");
 }

Comment: It looks valid. I just don't know the folder structure for ../../../register.php

Comment: Its actually a 3 stage page the main page is located /root/ while the page that the 2 pages above is /root/models/template/

Answer (score 0):

What I always do is get the error code or assign the text for the error on the validating page to a session variable, and then just echo out that session variable on the page where you want the user to see the variable. Don't forget to include session_start(); at the beginning of each page though!

Comment: this is kind of late, sorry, but what you do is:
**session_start();
$_SESSION['errormessage']="whatever error message: ".$error."whatever";**
<--ON YOUR ERROR PAGE. Then, on your other page you want to do:
**session_start();
echo $_SESSION['errormessage'];**